# Is there any angular built in module or any other method to prevent editing fields using browser inspect tools

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms, html-input, web-inspector, angular-validation

As an example, if I disabled
<input type="text" name="fullName" disabled [(ngModel)]="fullNameValue">
In my angular application, I can remove disabled attribute using inspect tools. then, I can change the value inside it. How to prevent this in angular frontend. Is there angular built in module or tag to prevent this.
Or else is there any method to prevent the user accessing inspect tools or prevent accessing inspect tools for this part only.

[html input tag with disabled attribute. Here I can't input text in the Customer Id input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olue2.jpg)

[after remove disabled attribute using inspect tools I can enable the Customer Id input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEE8q.jpg)

Comment: You can not have control over that in browser. you have to first validate data submitted by user server side.